# How to write an equation for a spline regression

Tags: regression, model

I have this basic regression model that I would like to make into a spline with a knot at -1. How would I write it? Is it possible for me to write it as a single equation where I subtract 1? Here's the basic model without the spline:

y0 = b0 + b1(Time 1 grade) + b3(Covariates) + e